# TCP Client is not Connecting to IRC Adress

Tags: c#, irc, twitch, chatbot

I am trying to build an twitch-chatbot. I've read some tutorials and this is what I coded so far:

```
namespace IRC_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        public NetworkStream NetStream = null;
        public StreamReader StreamRead = null;
        public StreamWriter StreamWrite = null;

        public System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Socket_TcpClient;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program P = new Program();
            P.IRC_Connect();

            Console.Read();
        }

        public void IRC_Connect()
        {
            int port;
            string  nick, owner, server, oauth;

            nick = "xxx";
            Console.WriteLine("Bot Name: {0}", nick);
            oauth = "oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            Console.WriteLine("Password Token: {0}", oauth);
            owner = "xxx";
            Console.WriteLine("Bot owner name: {0}", owner);
            server = "irc.twitch.tv";
            Console.WriteLine("Server name: {0}", server);                   
            port = 6667;
            Console.WriteLine("Portnummber: {0} ", port);

            try
            {
                Socket_TcpClient = new TcpClient(server, port);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");

            IRCWork();

            try
            {
                NetStream = Socket_TcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamRead = new StreamReader(NetStream);
                StreamWrite = new StreamWriter(NetStream);
                SendData("PASS", oauth);
                SendData("NICK", nick);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Communication error");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void SendData(string cmd, string param)
        {
            if (param == null)
            {
                StreamWrite.WriteLine(cmd);
                StreamWrite.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(cmd);
            }
            else
            {
                StreamWrite.WriteLine(cmd + " " + param);
                StreamWrite.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(cmd + " " + param);
            }
        }

        public void IRCWork()
        {
            string[] Text;
            string data;
            bool shouldRun = true;
            while (shouldRun)
            {
                data = StreamRead.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                char[] charSeparator = new char[] { ' ' };
                Text = data.Split(charSeparator, 5);

                if (Text[0] == "PING")
                {
                    SendData("PONG", Text[1]);
                }

                if (Text.Length > 4) //is the command received long enough to be a bot command?
                {
                    string command = Text[3]; //grab the command sent

                    switch (command)
                    {
                        case ":!join":
                            SendData("JOIN", Text[4]);
                            //if the command is !join send the "JOIN" command to the server with the parameters set by the user
                            break;
                        case ":!say":
                            SendData("PRIVMSG", Text[2] + " " + Text[4]);
                            //if the command is !say, send a message to the chan (ex[2]) followed by the actual message (ex[4]).
                            break;
                        case ":!quit":
                            SendData("QUIT", Text[4]);
                            //if the command is quit, send the QUIT command to the server with a quit message
                            shouldRun = false;
                            //turn shouldRun to false - the server will stop sending us data so trying to read it will not work and result in an error. This stops the loop from running and we will close off the connections properly
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (StreamRead != null)
                StreamRead.Close();
            if (StreamWrite != null)
                StreamWrite.Close();
            if (NetStream!= null)
                NetStream.Close();
            if (Socket_TcpClient != null)
                Socket_TcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is the connection part. I don't get far enough to test the rest. The server address and the port should be correct but the program just stops here and nothing happens.
(I've used the info from this site: http://help.twitch.tv/customer/com/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc)

```
try
{
    Socket_TcpClient = new TcpClient(server, port);
}
```

I hope someone knows the answer for my problem.

Comment: Any exceptions or the program just stops?

Comment: Ok I was impatient. It throws an timeout exceptions after a few minutes. But still the server and port should be correct.

Comment: Can you add the exception messages to your question?

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException;  A connection attempt failed, because of an Timeout or the host connection was broken. [translated from german]

Comment: I can telnet `irc.twitch.tv` on port 6667 just fine. Either something's wrong with your network, or the server ignores packets from your IP address.

Comment: You´re right its an network issue I will try it later from home. Thank you Frédéric.

Comment: You should try reading data from the server after you sent your authentication messages. That way you are sure you don't miss anything that the server has to say regarding your connection and authentication attempt. Maybe something like `:tmi.twitch.tv NOTICE * :Error logging in` that appears to me when I log in with a made up OAuth token in the `PASS` message.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gotten a chance to test your code, but I have built this class for my Twitch Bot

**IrcClient.cs**:

```
class IrcClient
{
    public string userName;
    private string channel;

    private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private StreamReader inputStream;
    private StreamWriter outputStream;

    public IrcClient(string ip, int port, string userName, string password)
    {
        this.userName = userName;

        tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        inputStream = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
        outputStream = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

        outputStream.WriteLine("PASS " + password);
        outputStream.WriteLine("NICK " + userName);
        outputStream.WriteLine("USER " + userName + " 8 * :" + userName);
        outputStream.Flush();
    }

    public void joinRoom(string channel)
    {
        this.channel = channel;
        outputStream.WriteLine("JOIN #" + channel);
        outputStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
// Password from www.twitchapps.com/tmi/
// include the "oauth:" portion
/* main server: irc.twitch.tv, 6667 */
string oauth = "oauth:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
irc = new IrcClient("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "BOT_NAME", oauth);
irc.joinRoom("CHANNEL_NAME");
```